# wireless internet stops working suddenly

Tags: wireless-router

I have an **ASUS N56-U**. Most of the time it works as intended. However when I am torrenting large files, upwards of 2GB, it ceases the wireless internet. The router does broadcast but there is no internet.

The only way to make it work again is that I manually switch off the router and switch it on again.

Is there a way to solve this problem? If so how?

Comment: Does it work wired?

Comment: Yes it does. @JourneymanGeek

Comment: Ah. A lot of 'bad' routers don't really like torrents and things like DHCP seem to crash. Asus *should* be ok. Does this happen when you download torrents over a cable?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek never tried it. However, i tried torrenting some smaller files. Files that are 1GB. It crashes again.